# Why is child table data not retrieved after renaming the table in SQL Server?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

In SQL server I renamed my table TrialOrderStockNumbers to TrialOrderStock. A foreign key points back to the TrialOrders table. In the EF designer I deleted the TrialOrderStockNumbers  entity and ran the Update Model From Database wizard (adding back the table TrialOrderStock). When I run the application the child data is now missing.

Now in SQL Profiler no query executes to get the Stock data. Before making the change profiler showed a statement selecting the data. I have had to discard all my changes and (for now) I plan to leave the old table name.

I'm using Entity Framework database first. **Why did Entity Framework stop retrieving child data after renaming the table in SQL Server and updating the model?**

Comment: Did updating the model change the navigation property?

Comment: I believe it did. Before discarding my changes I used SourceSafe to view the changes made. Every reference to TrialOrderStockNumbers was changed to TrialOrderStock as far as I could tell.

Answer (score 0):

It has been a while since I worked with MEF, where I had a similar issue with the entities getting out of sync with the database schema. As far as I recall, I simply re-generated the domain service and the problem was resolved.